# ASP.NET scrape data with System.Windows.Forms.webbrowser

Tags: c#, asp.net, webbrowser-control, console-application

Currently I'm using WinForm to scrape data from the Internet. In WinForm I have a Web-Browser control that loop over 10 websites, each loop will go through 3 steps. I'm using `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` events to capture when each step is completed, and then move to next website once the current Website has gone through all 3 steps and complete them.

I tried to do the same in ASP.NET, but calling the `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` event does not occur until the postback is completed. I tried to do the same using Console application and the same problem.

May I know how may I migrate this program to Web-application? How to construct a button's clicking event to start scrapping process?

Thanks.

Comment: How far did you tried to do that? Where is your code? What are you using?

Comment: C#, what do you mean by how far? I'm using the same working code from WinForms and copy to ASP.NET of the idea.

Comment: You said about execution time. If we will not consider that, does your scrapping works?

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you're trying to say.